# Sufficiently high power of a function is smooth

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $f(x)$ is a positive, continuous and bounded function. Is it true that the $k$-th power of $f$ is, say, $C^2$ (i.e. bounded first and second derivatives) for some $k$ big enough? I feel like higher powers should "smooth" the function, but I'm having trouble showing this.

Comment: that's not exactly true. the absolute value isn't differentiable, but its square is

Comment: Ah okay, I've deleted my comment

Comment: I don't think this works for powers of a typical realization of the Wiener process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this function is a counter-example:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
2 & x \leq -1 \\
\sqrt{|x|} + 1 & -1 < x \leq 1 \\
2 & x > 1
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Why som complicated? I guess you yould simply use $\sqrt{|x|}+1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: $|x|+1$ is even simpler.

Comment: i might say i think the graph of the function is prettier, but honestly this was just the first thing i thought of